# With HTML/CSS, how do I transition from one image to another using an animated mask?

Tags: html, css, animation, gif

I have two images in an HTML page. One is black-and-white, the other is color. I would like to transition from the black-and-white image to the color image using a custom animation. The effect I'm looking for is where the image appears black-and-white, and then appears to be "painted" in color, stroke-by-stroke.

The easiest way I can think to do this is to create an animated gif that starts white and gets painted black, stroke-by-stroke. Then I could place the color image on top of the black-and-white image using absolute positioning and mask the color image with the animated gif.

However, before pursuing that I searched all over to see if anyone had ever done anything like that, and I've been unable to turn up any examples. Is that even possible, and can you show an example of it?

Or, is there a better way to achieve this effect?

Comment: If you go the animated gif route, couldn't you just do the full animation in one image and forgo the multiple images, layers, and positioning?

Comment: Why do I overthink things? Thanks for restoring some sanity. Now I'm just curious if this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

If you have just two images then cross fading two overlayed images is pretty simple

```
 @keyframes cf3FadeInOut {
  0% {
  opacity:1;
}
45% {
opacity:1;
}
55% {
opacity:0;
}
100% {
opacity:0;
}
}

#cf3 img.top {
animation-name: cf3FadeInOut;
animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-duration: 10s;
animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

Look here at demo 3 & 4 http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/

Answer (score 0):

I have done half of the work for you

for this html

```
<id class="base">
</id>
```

and this CSS

```
.base {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    position: absolute;
}

.base:before, .base:after {
    background-image: url("http://placekitten.com/200/300"); 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
}

.base:after {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
    -webkit-mask-size: 200px 200px;
    -webkit-mask-image: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 70px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 80px); 
}
```

You get (in 2 pseudo elements) the original image and the image turned in grayscale. (You need a webkit browser for this).

Then , the grayscale image is turned transparent with an mask file.

I don't have any gif with transparencies, so I can not test the final result, but I think that it should work. (Just change .webkit-mask-image to url(gif)

Share your result if it works !

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/aPsX8/1/)

And yes, it is a overkill, but once you get it working you can adapt with no work to another image !

## [updated demo with an animated gif as mask](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/aPsX8/2/)